# Make a model invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I am using the entity framework and do not know how to add `[Required]`
Bearing in mind i cant change the database. And changing the required on the designer causes the mis-match error.

So through code on my controller, i want to check if the field is null or not, and send back a modelstate error.

However, even with the `if` commented out, it still does not work.

```
        //  if (myModel.myField == null)
            ModelState.AddModelError("myField", "This field is Required");

        // For some reason, it is still valid.
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(myModel);
        }
```

Comment: not able to understand ur question??

Comment: Use a viewmodel that you can use annotation attributes on, or use a metadata class with annotations.

Comment: @CodeCaster But the entity framework generates the model. I dont know how to access it, or if modifications would be regenerated.

Comment: EF generates partial classes.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see what you meant from ssg's answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a view model (a separate class) instead of the entity and mark the field `Required` there. This incurs some overhead (copying field values, additional code) but it's better to represent the mismatch between app behavior and domain model using classes than hardcoded tweaks.

That also allows behavior to be propagated to other actions using the same model without any additional code.

Comment: Although this might be a better approach, it does not answer the question as to why calling AddModelError does not set ModelState.IsValid to false.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey is right, it doesnt explain why its not working :(

Comment: fair enough. but even if it worked it should not be practiced anyway. "model invalidation" must only happen during binding, not manually. in fact that would kill the purpose of model binding and using "modelstate", so hard coding it would be equally good.